# Mysql unique value or empty string

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

I have an email mailing list table. There is an activation key for each user that signs up. The activation key is initially created upon signup. Each key is unique.

Once the user confirms registration this is an emptry string in the database.

Is there a way of me creating a unique contraint if there is null in the field.

In other words all value if not null or emptry string that are unique are allowed.

I set to unique and allow null but this does not work. I cant enter null and unique values, i.e. null multiple times when set to null unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't be able to create a unique constraint like that because a unique constraint is just that, unique, and multiple rows with NULL or an empty string would be duplicated rows. However, I would recommend you **not** empty out this column and rather use a boolean field that indicates registration was confirmed - it's a lot more straight forward and then you can use a unique constraint on that field.

Comment: best to use an enum or boolean value?, also in subscription table I have facebook id and one field, a user may not always signin with facebook but this needs to be unique- again the same could happen this could be null- in this instance do i seperate out and create a join, i.e. keep unique with join for facebook id

Comment: @MatthewChambers - my apologies, with MySQL you can have multiple NULL values inside a UNIQUE key. Therefore as long as you're setting the value to NULL you can still place a UNIQUE key on those fields - but you **cannot** set them to an empty string.

Comment: In other words say i had a user table and facebook id as a field. Is it best to add unique null to this field or create a table with facebook_id and user_id and join user_id in user table to user_id in facebook table where values are unique and set a left join

Comment: @MatthewChambers - in my opinion it is much better to create a separate table as you described and link them because every user doesn't have a Facebook id attached and so you're delineating that in the database design. Further, it makes a more concrete unique key because that could just be a compound primary key if you wanted.

Comment: @MatthewChambers - If this answered your question please mark it as the answer and I'll also modify the answer to include some of the content we just discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

in mysql

column or unique index only check constraint when all values filled without null values